# TensorFlow, what is t in inverse_time_decay?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use [inverse time decay of learning rate](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#inverse_time_decay), and the formula is

```
decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate / (1 + decay_rate * t)
```

And there is a example

```
...
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
learning_rate = 0.1
k = 0.5
learning_rate = tf.train.inverse_time_decay(learning_rate, global_step, k)

# Passing global_step to minimize() will increment it at each step.
learning_step = (
    tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    .minimize(...my loss..., global_step=global_step)
)
```

in the example above, `k` is the `decay_rate`, but how to set `t`? Does `t` is `global_step`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t would be the global step.  Global step is a variable which is incremented by one after every training step is completed.  If you want some sort of other t you can pass in any tensor you like as the "global_step".